# Is there a better way to implement a functional recursive findById in javascript than this?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I dislike loops, however this seems easy to solve with a loop and hard using functional programming. Here's the loop version:

```
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var result = collection[i].findById(id);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Since this is a common pattern, I expected to find a functional alternative in lodash. However the best I could come up with is this:

```
return _.first(_.compact(_.map(collection, e => e.findById(id)));
```

Not only is this ugly, but it will call findById on every element of the collection when it could return after the first one returns truthy.

How do you implement this?

Comment: Well if `_.some()` would return the truthy value from its predicate, that'd help, but it doesn't :(

Comment: What about _.find()?

Comment: _.find() returns the element, not the result of findById :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have these two functions

```
let uncurry = f => (x,y) => f(x)(y);
let reduce = f => i => xs => xs.reduce(uncurry(f), i);
```

You can write a simple `findById`

```
let findById = id => reduce(y => x => y || x.findById(id))(null);
```

Use it like this

```
findById(15)(collection); // => result | null
```

It will still iterate over each item in your collection, but it is [short-circuit evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and will only call `findById` **until** a result is found.

---

Here's the ES5

```
var uncurry = function uncurry(f) {
  return function (x, y) {
    return f(x)(y);
  };
};
var reduce = function reduce(f) {
  return function (i) {
    return function (xs) {
      return xs.reduce(uncurry(f), i);
    };
  };
};

var findById = function findById(id) {
  return reduce(function (y) {
    return function (x) {
      return y || x.findById(id);
    };
  })(null);
};
```

---

If you want to stick with the underscore/lodash, you can use this

```
let findById = id => xs =>
  _.reduce(xs, (result, x) => result || x.findById(id), null);
```

Comment: I like that, I'll probably use `_.reduce(collection, (result, x) => result || x.findById(id), null);`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
_.find(collection, function(c) {
  return c.findById(id) === true;
});
```

If you want to use pure javascript:

```
function findFirstById(collection, id, pos) {
  pos = (typeof pos === 'undefined') ? 0 : pos;
  if (pos >= collection.length)
    return false;
  var result = collection[pos].findById(id);
  if (result)
    return result;
  else
    return findFirstById(collection, id, pos + 1);
}
```

Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it's not much better, but I guess you could use `some` to implement the short-circuting. Kinda misses the point of making things more readable with functional constructs, but it should work...

```
var result;
collection.some(function(datum){
    return (result = datum.findById(id)) || return result == true;
});
```

There is also `find` in the ES7 specification. When you have that available, you'll be able to do the following:

```
collection.find(function(datum){
    return datum.findById(id) !== null;
});
```